# Line breaking of URLs in bibliographies

Tags: horizontal-alignment, bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I have a problem with the line break of an URL. The URL can´t break correct and extends into the border. I´ve tried some things. Amongst others I loaded the package `breakurl`, but without any success. When I set the bibliography left-aligned there isn´t a problem. But I need it justified. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,                         
fontsize=11,                    
BCOR=10mm,
DIV=11
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                        
\usepackage{microtype}    
\usepackage[
    style=numeric, 
    maxnames=1,
    bibencoding=latin1,
    backend=bibtex8,
    defernumbers=true,
    hyperref=true,
    alldates=long
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}

\begin{filecontents}{bachelorarbeit_lit.bib}
@ONLINE{java96,
    author = {{Sun Microsystems}},
    title = {JavaSoft ships Java 1.0},
    year = {1996},
    month = {1},
    url = {http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0EIN/is_1996_Jan_23/ai_17853565/?tag=content;col1},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Sun},
    keywords = {www}
}

@ONLINE{java02,
    author = {{Computer Weekly}},
    title = {Write once, run anywhere?},
    year = {2002},
    month = {5},
    url = {http://www.computerweekly.com/Articles/2002/05/02/186793/Write-once-runanywhere1.htm},
    urldate = {2011-03-02},
    sortname = {Computer},
    keywords = {www}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bachelorarbeit_lit}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Test \cite{java02}
Test \cite{java96}

%\raggedright
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: do not use package `breakurl`, when running `pdflatex`. `hyperref` does it anyway ...

Comment: But without breakurl the problem is the same. Hyperref has an option breaklinks. But as far as i know this option doesn´t works. It will be set internally by the drivers.

Comment: I removed the {biblatex} tag because the problem at hand may also arise with other bibliography packages.

Comment: A general hint that might be helpful whenever you're writing anything in English: For typing an apostrophe (as in _can't_), don't use the acute accent `´` (which is right of the sharp s `ß`, assuming you have a German keyboard), but instead the actual apostrophe `'` by pressing `shift` + `#`. That'll give your LaTeX documents a way more professional look ;)

Comment: There will be a new solution for this problem in the near future (already tested and it will be uploaded to CTAN soon). Look at my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108001/28200

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first URL has a large unbreakable section (`runanywhere1`) which must either form the end of the second or the beginning of the third line (given the specific font size, margin etc. of the example) if one insists on justified text. An acceptable (?) solution may be obtained by adding e.g. `\sloppy` or `\emergencystretch 1.5em` before `\printbibliography`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is almost the same like the answer of Herbert and works too.

Answer (score 37):

try it this way: (without `\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}`)

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
\sloppy
\printbibliography
\endgroup
```

[image: Output, nicely spaced URLs with raggedright]

or without `\raggedright`:

[image: Output, nicely fittet URLs without raggedright]