# bibtex large spacing

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, urls

I couldn't find a solution to my problem searching. Apologies if it has been asked before.

My problem is: on a few of my bibliography entries, there are massive spaces in the text to pad out the lines, how can I avoid this to improve the appearance?

[image]

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15653/perform-a-line-break-of-an-url-in-bibliography-manually-biblatex-hyperref) help with your problem?

Comment: Ahh, it did! Thank you very much @doncherry. I noticed the `hyphenbreaks` option in the `breakurl` package which solved my problem

Comment: Great! So if your problem was the same as the one in the other question, we could close this thread as a duplicate, or you should post your solution as an answer here and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by including the `hyphenbreaks` option in the `breakurl` package.

```
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\edef\UrlBreaks{\do\-\UrlBreaks}% after loading url or hyperref
...
...
\begingroup
\RaggedRight
\bibliographystyle{...}
\bibliography{...}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's getting closer, although it's not quite right: [bib entry](http://i.imgur.com/sMNvp.png).

Would including some of my preable be helpful?

Comment: provide the complete source of the bib entry

Comment: @misc{pokerBOOM,
  title = {After `Black Friday,' American Poker Faces Cloudy Future},
  author = {Nate Silver},
  howpublished = {\url{http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/04/20/after-black-friday-american-poker-faces-cloudy-future/}},
  year = {(accessed May 10, 2011)},
}