# Long URL in Bibliography section exceeds the bounds of the page

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have an external bib where I put a reference to an external URL.

```
@misc{myreference,
  author = {The Author},
  title = {The Title},
  howpublished = "\url{http://thisismyurl/2010/3/a-long-url-here}",
  year = {year}
}
```

When I compile, the URL (when displayed in Bibliography) exceeds the bounds of the page (set as customs). The URL is composed by different terms concatenated with `-` symbol. `a-long-url-here` can be the following:

```
abc-abc-abca-abc-ab-abc-abc-abc-a-abcabc-ab-abc-abc/
```

The bib is inserted in the following manner:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEbib}
\bibliography{bibliog}
```

Is there any mechanism to fix this behaviour? I checked [Line breaking of URLs in bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15653/perform-a-line-break-of-an-url-in-bibliography-manually-biblatex-hyperref) but I don't know how to use it in my situation.

**Edit**

For the sake of completeness, I use **PdfLatex**.

Comment: Did you try the suggested `\sloppy` and `\emergencystretch` settings?

Comment: @mafp No. Where do I have to put these commands? Thanks.

Comment: since the `url` package allows breaks, it sounds like you are using `hyperref`, which doesn't allow them by default.  if you specify the option `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}` you should get better results.  of course, this is just a guess; i'm not familiar with the `IEEEbib` style, so it may apply some restrictions i'm not aware of.

Comment: Indeed, try barbara's tip with `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}` first. Note that this will only work when you produce pdf output.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for your reply. but that package does not work for me.

Comment: It gives me **Option clash for package hyperref.**

Comment: To avoid the option clash, you can type `\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}`.

Comment: @Mico no chance. I set `\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}` followed by `\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}` but the error still remains the same.

Comment: Don't provide both of these instructions, but only the first one -- *after* the `hyperref` package has been loaded either directly by one of your own instructions or indirectly by one of the packages you load (or by the document class).

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your support but the url does not break correctly. Is there any option that I can use for url package?

Comment: Have you tried Barbara Beeton's suggestion, which was to load the `url` package with the `hyphens` option set: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`? Do load this package *before* loading `hyperref`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your reply. What packages do I have to use (if possible list them)? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I've provided an answer with an MWE (minimum working example) that shows how you may get a URL string to break at hyphens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have a file named `bibliog.bib` with the contents given in your posting, the following MWE (minimum working example) generates a reference with the URL string broken at a hyphen. The key steps are (i) load the `url` package *with* the `hyphens` option and (ii) enable the `breaklinks=true` option of the `hyperref` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true}
\setlength\textwidth{4in} % simulate a very narrow line width
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} % *not* IEEEbib...
\bibliography{bibliog}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked mentioned here in my case.
Finally \usepackage{xurl} worked in my case. I followed the following link answer [Forcing a bibliography link with very long file name to stay within column width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492393/forcing-a-bibliography-link-with-very-long-file-name-to-stay-within-column-width)