# Forcing a bibliography link with very long file name to stay within column width

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

[image]

The image above is for a reference in double-column `IEEEtran` class.

One potential solution is mentioned in [Forcing linebreak in bibliography with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458049/forcing-linebreak-in-bibliography-with-natbib/458066#458066), but this works when there are no single extremely long words in the link. The link above contains a long PDF file name

`PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf`

The name is too long that it cannot fit in one column, but LaTeX still does not hyphenate it.

The solution in [Forcing linebreak in bibliography with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458049/forcing-linebreak-in-bibliography-with-natbib/458066#458066) yields

[image]

Thus, further decrease in the link size is needed.

**Is there a way to force it to stay within the column width while maintain an intact hyperlink?**

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@online{lovelace2015low,
    author = {{Lovelace, Will}},
    title = {{Low SCR Wind Integration and Mitigation}},
    url = {http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
    organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
    date = {2015-11-11},
    urldate = {2019-05-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{lovelace2015low}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an current tex distribution you can use package `xurl` like this (see marking `<====` in the code):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@online{lovelace2015low,
    author = {{Lovelace, Will}},
    title = {{Low SCR Wind Integration and Mitigation}},
    url = {http://www.cce.umn.edu/documents/CPE-Conferences/MIPSYCON-PowerPoints/2015/PGLowSCRWindGenerationInstabilityIdentificationandMitigation.pdf},
    organization = {Minnkota Power Cooperative},
    date = {2015-11-11},
    urldate = {2019-05-20}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{xurl} % <===================================================
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}

\cite{lovelace2015low}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]