# How can I break a long URL in bibliography

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I have a problen with a long url on LaTeX, I want to break it but I don't know how.

The line in LaTeX is:

```
\bibitem{} Information Intel 8085: \\ \url{http://www.ehowenespanol.com/informacion-microprocesador-intel-8085-sobre\_138668/}
```

When I compile, I can see in PDF the following url:

```
http://www.ehowenespanol.com/informacion-microprocesador-intel-80
-138668/
```

Can I make some kind of \breakline or \  in the url?

Comment: First of all replace `\_` by `_`, `\url` will escape it automatically. Secondly remember that there are rules as to how one can break URLs. In this case it can only be broken at `/`, `.` and `_`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15653/15925, or one of several other questions on this site.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `url` package with the `hyphens` option set? Doing so instructs LaTeX that it's permissible to break a long URL string at a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this problem. I only used `\nolinkurl`:

```
\bibitem{}

\href{http://www.ehowenespanol.com/informacion-microprocesador-intel-8085-sobre\_138668/}{\nolinkurl{http://www.ehowenespanol.com/} \\ \nolinkurl{informacion-microprocesador-intel-8085-sobre\_138668/}}
```

Thanks to @daleif,  @Andrew Swann,  @Mico for read my post