# Footnotes are formatted wrong/messy

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I have a problem with formatting my footnotes. They look very messy and just wrong. I could not find a way to change that, but I assume it is some kind of property, like with a \usepackage[] commant or anything similar. I use the online Latex editor and compiler writelatex.com, so it can't be a problem of my compiling properties.

Does anybody have a hint for me how this issue can be fixed?
Here is a screenshot of the messy footnotes. The command I use for the footnotes is just
    \footnote{Title. Link: http://www.link.li. [Date]
[image: Footnotes formatted wrong]

Comment: You need to allow the url's to break.  Start by using the [`url` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) and writing these as `\url{http://www.w3.org}`.  Then if there as still problems, look at other questions here about breaking url's, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15653/15925

Comment: Thank you for this information. Unfortunately it won't let me use the \url command within the footnote, and I am pretty sure this online editor/compiler is using all necessary packages already. Is there anything else I need to consider?

Edit: \usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} didn't help as well.

Comment: What editor are you using?  In standard LaTeX you can just write `\footnote{Title.  Link \url{http://www.w3.org} [Date]}`

Comment: I am using the online editor www.writelatex.com. So it shouldn't be a editor or compiling problem, since I assume this online editor is using and providing all available packages. The editor is pretty good by the way, I really like it. But if I use the \url command I get an error:

`Undefined control sequence. <argument> ... Is Web 2.0. Verfügbar unter: \url {http://www.ttivanguard.co... l.50 ...dc05session4003.pdf}. [27. Dezember 2013]} . The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed.`   [etc]

Comment: If the `\url` command is not defined, then you need a `\usepackage{url}` in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked so far. And it already looks better, but is it normal, that footnotes are still looking like this: http://abload.de/img/formatnewinshf.png - It seems strange to me that they're "indent" after a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web addresses should be typed using the `\url` command.  This is provided by the [`url` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url), amongst others.  Provided there are not long strings of letters in the address then these will break over lines without further action.

Different formatting of the footnote may be provided by options from the [`footmisc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

Some text\footnote{Some interesting homepage on the web. Accessible at
\url{http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss} [12th December,
2009].  More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.
More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.

More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.} and
more text.

Some text\footnote{Some interesting homepage on the web. Accessible at
\url{http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss} [12th December,
2009].  More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.
More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.

More text to demonstrate the shape of the footnote paragraphs.} and
more text.

\end{document}
```