# underfull \hbox (badness 10000)

Tags: bibliographies, badness

Hi i have a a underfull \hbox (badness 10000) error in my bibliography list below but not sure why?

```
\bibitem{application 1}
K. Conrad
\textit{http://www.math.uconn.edu/$\sim$kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf} 
(accessed on 09/01/2016).
```

could anyone help?

Comment: get rid of `\textit` and `$\sim$` and use `\url` from the url package then latex will be able to break the line at a `/` in a URL so will be able to justify the text more easily

Comment: Hi! thanks ive changed it and used the package, it now says badness 3179?? do you have an ideas!

 \bibitem{trace norm web}
K. Conrad
\url{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf}
(accessed on 22/11/2015).

\bibitem{application 1}
K. Conrad
\url{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf} 
(accessed on 09/01/2016).

Comment: I have re-tagged your question since it does not really seem to be about `biblatex`, but rather a more manual way to create the bibliography. An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) would help us reproduce the actual error. Note that line breaking of URLs is always a very delicate matter (maybe even more so in the bibliography).

Comment: URLs in the bibliography are often quite difficult to handle. For some hints, see e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15653/line-breaking-of-urls-in-bibliographies), [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134191/line-breaks-of-long-urls-in-bibliography) or [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected).

Answer (score 3):

I always set a bibliography with long URLs ragged right:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
...

{\RaggedRight
 \begin{thebibliography}{...}
 \bibitem{application 1}
    K. Conrad
    \url{http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf} (accessed on 09/01/2016).
 ...
 \end{thebibliography}%
}
```

Or for a bib created by `bibtex`

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
...

{\RaggedRight
 \bibliographystyle{...}
 \bibliography{...}%
}
```

or for `biber`

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{...}
...

{\RaggedRight
 \printbibliography[...]%
}
```

Comment: i changed to the ragged right format and its worked! thanks so much :)